# Installing cx_Oracle 64-bit on AIX

Tags: python, oracle, pip, aix, cx-oracle

We are getting the below error while installing cx_Oracle using Python pip.

Note: Python, cx_Oracle, Oracle client and AIX ($OBJECT_MODE) are all 64-bit here.

```
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/e3/cfd4f413f8d47dd2aee09273d9bb3ee6aa7384e0a04e191d703c2199eb93/cx_Oracle-7.3.0.tar.gz (307kB)
     |################################| 317kB 18.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dc8n4c28/cx-Oracle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dc8n4c28/cx-Oracle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ktlmej97/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dc8n4c28/cx-Oracle/
    Complete output (71 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Oracle' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8
    creating build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src
    creating build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi
    creating build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src
    xlc_r -DNDEBUG -O -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/opt/include/python3.8 -c src/cxoBuffer.c -o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoBuffer.o
    .
    .
    .
    xlc_r -DNDEBUG -O -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/opt/include/python3.8 -c odpi/src/dpiGlobal.c -o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiGlobal.o
    "odpi/src/dpiGlobal.c", line 203.1: 1506-943 (W) Attribute "constructor" is not supported on the target platform and is ignored.
    xlc_r -DNDEBUG -O -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/opt/include/python3.8 -c odpi/src/dpiHandleList.c -o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiHandleList.o
    .
    .
    .
    xlc_r -DNDEBUG -O -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -I/opt/include -O2 -qmaxmem=-1 -qarch=pwr5 -q64 -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/opt/include/python3.8 -c odpi/src/dpiVar.c -o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiVar.o
    creating build/lib.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8
    /opt/lib/python3.8/config-3.8/ld_so_aix xlc_r -bI:/opt/lib/python3.8/config-3.8/python.exp build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoBuffer.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoConnection.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoCursor.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoDeqOptions.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoEnqOptions.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoError.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoFuture.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoLob.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoModule.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoMsgProps.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoObject.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoObjectAttr.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoObjectType.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoQueue.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSessionPool.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSodaCollection.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSodaDatabase.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSodaDoc.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSodaDocCursor.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSodaOperation.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoSubscr.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoTransform.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoUtils.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoVar.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoVarType.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiConn.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiContext.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiData.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiDebug.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiDeqOptions.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiEnqOptions.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiEnv.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiError.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiGen.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiGlobal.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiHandleList.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiHandlePool.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiLob.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiMsgProps.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiObject.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiObjectAttr.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiObjectType.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiOci.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiOracleType.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiPool.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiQueue.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiRowid.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSodaColl.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSodaCollCursor.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSodaDb.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSodaDoc.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSodaDocCursor.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiStmt.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiSubscr.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiUtils.o build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/odpi/src/dpiVar.o -o build/lib.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/cx_Oracle.so
    ld: 0711-736 ERROR: Input file build/temp.AIX.7203.1845.64-3.8/src/cxoBuffer.o:
        XCOFF64 object files are not allowed in 32-bit mode.
    error: command '/opt/lib/python3.8/config-3.8/ld_so_aix' failed with exit status 8
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dc8n4c28/cx-Oracle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dc8n4c28/cx-Oracle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ktlmej97/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Not sure where the version incompatibility issues are arising

Comment: Via [google](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/information-server-datastage-job-gets-compile-error-xcoff64-object-files-are-not-allowed-32-bit-mode) you may need to manually download and extract the cx_Oracle source, and then fiddle with the compiler options in setup.py before [building](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#install-using-source-from-pypi)  Or open an issue on https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues and to ask about the compiler etc used when cx_Oracle was tested on AIX.

Comment: Please edit your post to note what command you're running

Comment: In file `/opt/lib/python3.8/config-3.8/ld_so_aix` change line `$CC $CCOPT $CCARGS` to `$CC -q64 $CCOPT $CCARGS` (Note if Python weren't so sophisticated, maybe it would use `libtool`... that is a tool that is meant to create shared objects even on exotic platforms like AIX)

Comment: Thank you Christopher and Lorinczy. I will get them a try and will get back to the post.

The command used was:

autohome/user5-nix # python -m pip install cx_Oracle --proxy=http://newproxy.tnet.internal:8080 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host fi>

Comment: It worked. Thanks @lorinczy-zsigmond.